# How do check an instance belongs to the login user?

Tags: django

Below is how I currently check that a model belongs to the user that's editing it. I do this in `views.py` for almost everything, it's a bit repetitive, I use it a lot!

```
 # If we have an instance check that it belongs to the login.
        if some_object.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

So, I'm wondering how others address such functionality? I have been thinking about moving this to each on save method for all objects?

Could I have examples (with code) of how Django developers do this, there must be a better wayfor checking what user can edit what, right?

I won't rush into accepting an answer, I'm really interested in authoritative responses from more experienced devs as I'm very new to Django.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you doing these checks in your views? Specifically, are you using class based views?

Comment: Yes this are class based views. What and the model option?

Answer (score 2):

Mixins could work if you are using class based views... You can create your own by doing something like this

```
class RequireOwnershipMixin(object):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(RequireOwnershipMixin, self).get_object(queryset)
        if obj.user != self.request.user:
            return None
        return obj
```

and your view would now look something like this

```
class UpdateSomeObjectView(RequireOwnershipMixin, UpdateView):
    ...
```

This will override the `get_object` method to return `None` if you are not the owner of the object. You may need to do some extra checks in the `get` or `post` methods to handle when `None` is returned so that you can return a `HttpResponseForbidden`

You can also use this for any class based views that utilize the `get_object` method.